# WARN io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.internal.state.AsynchronousMetricStorage in open telemetry agent 1.15

Tags: java, spring-boot, newrelic, open-telemetry

Getting following warnings for Spring application with in open telemetry agent 1.15:

> [otel.javaagent 2022-06-22 14:45:13:965 +0530] [PeriodicMetricReader-1] WARN io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.internal.state.AsynchronousMetricStorage - Instrument db.client.connections.idle.min has recorded multiple values for the same attributes.
> [otel.javaagent 2022-06-22 14:45:13:972 +0530] [PeriodicMetricReader-1] WARN io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.internal.state.AsynchronousMetricStorage - Instrument db.client.connections.max has recorded multiple values for the same attributes.
> [otel.javaagent 2022-06-22 14:45:13:976 +0530] [PeriodicMetricReader-1] WARN io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.internal.state.AsynchronousMetricStorage - Instrument db.client.connections.pending_requests has recorded multiple values for the same attributes.

Anyone idea?